# Code Signing Identity Before Submitting to the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, code-signing

Before I submit my app to the app store, do the debug and release have to be both set to distribution or should the debug be set to developer and release set to distribution.  Here is a picture of what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building for the app store will build under the `release` profile, and building while debugging will build under the `debug` profile. This is exactly why they are separate entries, so you DON'T have to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

When the time of app submission you will obviously choose release mode then your RELEASE macro is activated(RELESE=1). So it doesn't matter what profile you are choosing in Debug section.